# Service Host: Local system (network restricted) is thrashing hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, performance, services, task-manager

I am having windows 8.1 with update 1 installed and all release updates of windows till the date i am posting this questions. System is laptop, Core i3 with 6 GB RAM and 500GB hard disk.

When ever i restart my CPU or resume it from hibernate or sleep, "Service Host: Local system (network restricted)" process which i can see in task manager along with many other child services, is taking 100% Hard Disk.

These process makes system very slow not even at startup but sometimes, they drill the hard disk anytime they want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 hard disk usage 100%](http://superuser.com/questions/649862/windows-8-hard-disk-usage-100)

Comment: It is not duplicate and even IMPOSSIBLE duplicate because the question you referring as duplicate is discussing the system infected with virus and virtual memory which is thrashing hard disk. I am having 6GB RAM out of which only 2 GB is used and 4GB is still free mean no virtual memory issue. Secondly about virus issue, i am having up to date Kaspersky Anti Virus and scanned the system also. It is clean.

Comment: Try this one then [Windows 8 disk usage is 100%](http://superuser.com/q/639048)

Comment: no. this is not solving my issue, i have already tried, defrag, cleanup, chkdsk, disk health

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/830372/hard-drive-windows-8-pro-100-disk-usage-whenever-running-any-program#comment1090463_830372

Comment: @magicandre1981 the post you mentioned is not solved.

Comment: look at my comment and provide the trace of the disk usage

Comment: have you captured a disk trace?

Comment: Still not. Intact I'm having difficulty to do that. Isn't there any easy tool to trace disk?

Comment: I think this is very easy. Install the WPT and copy/paste the command into a cmd.exe: http://pastebin.com/AyxAVU60

Comment: [WPT Report Link](http://tinyurl.com/wpt-report) Here is the report i have uploaded.

Comment: @magicandre1981 i have uploaded the report of WPT Tools. Please provide response to me now that what is fault basically.

Comment: I posted an answer. Check it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I really appreciate the help by the user @magicandre1981. Apart from that the solution that I came to have is to disable Superfetch service in Windows. Microsoft says it improves system performance over time by seeing program usage but what I research on the internet, many users complained about it that initially when system is newly installed, it runs ok but within time, Superfetch starts thrashing hard disk.

To experiment it my self, I first stopped this service, then suddenly my hard disk usage dropped from 98 percent to 5 percent. Immediately I found that it was culprit. I disabled this service and when I hibernated system, to my surprise, the hibernate is very fast now. As well as resume was more fast than ever.

The concern that Microsoft says that it improves the performance, what I see that after disabling Superfetch Service, system performance is increase instead of dropping.

Answer (score 8):

The HDD usage comes from the superfetch service which preloads data from the HDD into the RAM:

[image]

Starting with Vista this service loads data into the RAM to speedup the performance of Windows. Also starting with Vista, the IO activities also have priorities like processes. And superfetch runs at very low priority. So it should not affect other IO activity, because normal IO activity runs at a high priority.

I can see that you have some 3rd party drivers running, maybe this impacts the HDD performance. Remove them and see what happens.

If this also doesn't speedup the performance, replace the WD Scorpio Black (WDC WD5000BEKT-75KA9T0) HDD with a SSD.

Comment: which 3rd party drivers? please tell. i am having issues so i am complaining. It is not minor effect. it is huge effect on performance. really.

Comment: look the picture: eubakup.sys and eubkmon.sys. Looks like both are part of EaseUS Todo Backup.

Comment: I know they are part of it.  So should i disable EaseUS Todo Backup Service name "EaseUS Agent Service"?

Comment: EUBKMON.sys is a Windows driver. A driver is a small software program that allows your computer to communicate with hardware or connected devices and EUBakup.sys is an important file process that locates in the Windows\System32\ or folder, it guarantees Windows system's stability and the function of program that require this file process. Both are not EaseUS Todo Backup files.

Comment: they are not part of Windows. I don't have them. Remove the backup tool and see if the HDD issue is gone

Comment: I got these definitions from internet. Anyways. Anyways, instead of uninstalling EaseUS Todo Backup application (because i use it for the backup tasks), i have disable both of its services named "EaseUS Agent Service" and "Guard Agent Service"

Comment: Where did this picture come from?  What utility produces it?

Comment: @Eric this is the WPA (Windows Perf Analyzer) to show the content of the ETL file which he generated with those steps: http://pastebin.com/AyxAVU60